# Adding datetime to each band's metadata in a multiband raster using Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I've created a multiband raster of individual rasters of temperature at different times over a period of two days using `rasterio` in the following way:

```
with rasterio.open('test.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    for id, layer in enumerate(file_list, start=1):
        with rasterio.open(layer) as src1:
            dst.write_band(id, src1.read(1))
```

Using gdalinfo to evaluate `test.tif` reveals lackluster metadata for the bands.

```
Band 1 Block=69x3 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=69x3 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 3 Block=69x3 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 4 Block=69x3 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

I've used [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284179/add-bands-name-and-description-to-the-metadata-when-stacking-using-rasterio) for adding a description to each band, but I have not found a way to add datetime to the metadata.

I've looked at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/290806/136004), but it only changes the description and doesn't add a new tag. Additionally, I would have to run it as a subprocess in python, and I'd prefer to do this entirely within python.

I've also looked at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214272/136004), but using the tag `TIFFTAG_DATETIME` with gdal's `ds.SetMetadata()` is not working. It doesn't throw an error but when I view the metadata using `gdalinfo` or `qgis` nothing shows up.

Does anybody know how to add a datetime property to the metadata of a multiband raster using python?

Comment: Trying to sort out what `gdalinfo` or other metadata viewers will pull for GeoTIFFs can be a world of pain. For a "data cube" such as yours are you able to write data out to a netCDF file? That format will have far richer metadata support baked in.

Comment: I could look into that if you think that's easier to edit the metadata!

Comment: In my opinion it is easier - you'll have to judge for yourself as to if it suits your purposes but here is a link to get started reading GeoTIFFs: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ds.update_tags(band, tag=value)`. See the [docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/tags.html#writing-tags) for additional info.

Here's an example with an existing dataset (opened in `r+` mode).

```
import rasterio as rio

with rio.open('test.tif', 'r+') as ds:
    for i in range(1, ds.count+1):
        # Here I add a non-standard tag called "DATE_TIME"
        # this can be anything, like "MY_CUSTOM_BAND_DATE_TIME_TAG"
        # Or you could use "TIFFTAG_DATETIME" if you want. Up to you...
        ds.update_tags(i, DATE_TIME='2021-05-08T14:30')
```

[image]

Your code would look something like:

```
with rasterio.open('test.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    for id, layer in enumerate(file_list, start=1):
        with rasterio.open(layer) as src1:
            dst.write_band(id, src1.read(1))
            dst.update_tags(id, DATE_TIME='2021-05-08T14:30')
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!!